# How do I efficiently get the index and value for a key from SortedDict?

Tags: python, sortedcontainers

Given a collection that is ordered and keyed (like OrderedDict or [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) SortedDict) I want to do the following:

```
d['first'] = 'hi'
d['second'] = 'there'
d['third'] = 'world'
(ix, value) = d.get_index_and_value('second')
assert d.iloc[ix + 1] == 'third'
# or list(d.keys())[ix + 1] with OrderedDict
```

however I cannot see an efficient way to get both the index and the value given a key (`(ix, value) = d.get_index_and_value('second')`).

Is this possible with SortedDict, or another container?

In practice, my keys are a sortable collection (dates) if that means there is a better container I could use.

Comment: Seems the answer is no... I dug into the SortedDict source code and it stores a sorted list of keys and a `dict`, so I don't think there's an efficient way to do it with that data. I have tried storing tuplesof `(index, value)` in an OrderedDict and that works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` method of `keys`:

```
ix, value = d.keys().index('second'), d['second']
```

this will return

```
(1, 'there')
```

If you don't want to repeat yourself, you can make this a function, or extend `OrderedDict` to include this as a method:

```
def get_index_and_value(d, key):
    return d.keys().index(key), d[key]

print(get_index_and_value(d, 'second')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think index() is O(n). Seeing as the lookup has already found the item I was hoping that it could be more efficient than that.